# Match content between words

Tags: regex

I'd like to create a regex to match content between tags.

My regex that is not working : `new RegExp("page.content_before(.+)\/page.content_before", "g").exec(myText)[0]`

myText :

```
page.title
Accueil
/page.title

page.content_before
[slides]

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit excepturi consequatur inventore alias ducimus tenetur libero iste nesciunt soluta esse et debitis aliquid, voluptatum placeat veritatis! At dolorem repellat doloremque!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      [articles]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      [vehicles]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
/page.content_before

page.content
<div class="line">
  <div class="col-8">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam officiis eos quis eum in sapiente aliquid placeat excepturi ratione suscipit quisquam exercitationem necessitatibus totam vel, ullam assumenda optio aspernatur incidunt.
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    Social.
  </div>
</div>
/page.content


page.content_after
[googlemap]
/page.content_after


page.seo_title
Accueil
/page.seo_title


page.seo_url
accueil
/page.seo_url
```

The result should be :

```
[slides]

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit excepturi consequatur inventore alias ducimus tenetur libero iste nesciunt soluta esse et debitis aliquid, voluptatum placeat veritatis! At dolorem repellat doloremque!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      [articles]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="line">
    <div class="col-12">
      [vehicles]
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No duplicate. Please take a look of my message.

Comment: Don't use regex for parsing/dissecting HTML. So instead of fixing the regex, use a proper HTML parser. And that is exactly what the duplicate has as answer. It applies here too.

Comment: escape dots with `\.` and add regex flag `s` - it forces dot to match new lines,- that is why your regex wasn't working. p.s. No such thing as "proper parser" - if you feel comfortable parsing HTML with regex - do so, it's simple as that.